# how can I use a class that extends JdbcDaoSupport?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using a class that extends from JdbcDaoSupport and now I am getting an error of

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
```

I really have no idea how to indicate this, so this class wont throw an exception.

The class looks like this:

```
package org.springframework.jdbc.core.support;

import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport;
import org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator;

public abstract class JdbcDaoSupport extends DaoSupport {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JdbcDaoSupport() {
    }

    public final void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        if(this.jdbcTemplate == null || dataSource != this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = this.createJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
            this.initTemplateConfig();
        }

    }

    protected JdbcTemplate createJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public final DataSource getDataSource() {
        return this.jdbcTemplate != null?this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource():null;
    }

    public final void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        this.initTemplateConfig();
    }

    public final JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return this.jdbcTemplate;
    }

    protected void initTemplateConfig() {
    }

    protected void checkDaoConfig() {
        if(this.jdbcTemplate == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("\'dataSource\' or \'jdbcTemplate\' is required");
        }
    }

    protected final SQLExceptionTranslator getExceptionTranslator() {
        return this.getJdbcTemplate().getExceptionTranslator();
    }

    protected final Connection getConnection() throws CannotGetJdbcConnectionException {
        return DataSourceUtils.getConnection(this.getDataSource());
    }

    protected final void releaseConnection(Connection con) {
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, this.getDataSource());
    }
}
```

But I guess I have to include the dataSource in the class that extends of this. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: you have entries for JDBC template and datasource in your spring config? and while startup connection was created?

Comment: no, I didnt configure any jdbc, I used spring boot with the autoconfig annotation

Comment: this is my guess, I have limited knowledge in spring boot. In application.properties file we need to specify the data source information such as connection url, username and password from there it picks up I believe. But I am not sure if this will work.